# не могу зайти в visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Скачал vs 2019 с официального сайта, но при входе в аккаунт майкрософт выскакивает ошибка. В чем проблема?
[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0):

Есть вероятность, что [это поможет](https://coderoad.ru/45276188/Visual-Studio-2017-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Краткая выжимка в виде картинки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Недостаточно в ответе дать ссылку. Приведите хотя бы краткую выжимку из сути ответа. Ссылка может переехать, например, и ответ перестанет быть полезным.